# Why make a website screen reader accessible?

Tags: html, accessibility

I'm rather new to webdev, and I quickly got the impression that all websites should be made screen reader accessible. Documentation is written with a tone that seems to exert that the website must be made screen reader accessible as the default choice. I've read about how to make it accessible, but nothing about why. I suspect that anyone asking "why" will be shunned as insensitive, discriminating, etc., none of which is relevant to the objective of this question.

I ask for an unbiased and objective list of pros and cons of making a website screen reader accessible. This is to inform webdevs interested in this (including myself) on when and why they should or shouldn't make their website accessible. Here is what I have so far:

Pros:

- Website is accessible to users using screen readers
- Compliance for companies that require accessibility

Cons:

- Additional development time/expense
- Additional markup -> bigger files -> hosting costs
- Full compliance restricts layout/design

What other considerations are there, direct or indirect? Does making a website screen reader accessible make it somehow better even for unimpaired users? Are non-accessible websites without any accessibility requirements ever penalized?

Comment: I think two things to consider is the fact that making your website accessible really only helps make it better (doesn't affect your typical users but users who depend on accessibility will appreciate it) and a lot of the best practices for accessibility are the best practices for SEO as well. I don't think this question is truly a good fit for SO though.

Comment: Where else would be a better place to ask this question? Or, where can I read about this information I'm seeking? I did not find anything on Google about the "why".

Comment: @DavidTan - WIth an aging population that have visual and physical ailments, but are quite well off and deserve respect, why cut off that customer base

Comment: @EdHeal `WIth an aging population that have visual and physical ailments, but are quite well off and deserve respect, why cut off that customer base` What do you mean? My customer base is university students.

Comment: So you do not have students that are mature, have physical difficulties, visual impairment. A university that does not want to be inclusive?

Comment: @EdHeal `So you do not have students that are mature, have physical difficulties, visual impairment. A university that does not want to be inclusive?` With your loaded question, you are pushing me away from making the website accessible. I think that's decided then, thank you! I will keep my website the way it is.

Comment: How am I doing that. You should make it inclusive as it is your job to do so. Your university has all students with 20-20 visual, not physically disabled etc.

Comment: @DavidTan Not sure if I can comment where you can read about it. There are a lot of reasons why you want your website to be accessible. It seems like you are asking pros and cons on implementing accessibility which is subjective as you can see with some of the example pros and cons you mentioned (yeah more dev time is necessary so thats really up to your situation if its worth it. maybe your traffic targets people who use screen readers and maybe it doesn't).

Answer (score 2):

Good accurate markup in HTML will get this for free - along with accurate rendering in browsers.

It also aids search engines.

The design should be left to CSS. The screen readers do not care about this.

Also blind people, partially sighted customers are not to be sniffed at.

Comment: `The design should be left to CSS. The screen readers do not care about this.` I am making a website that is navigated by clicking pins on a map. How would you make this screen reader accessible, can it be done in CSS? I will ignore your comment about "blind people, partially sighted customers".

Comment: @DavidTan - For that example, if the pins were marked up as an unordered list `<ul>` and the list items positioned with CSS, the screen reader would read it as a list of clickable links.

Comment: There will be a few thousand pins, visually organized in clusters. Assuming I can figure out how to accomplish what you've described, then will the screen reader will be reading out the ID number of each pin?

Comment: You put them into a hierarchy.

Comment: Anyway for a person with 20-20 vision on a screen a 100 pins would be difficult to separate.

Comment: @EdHeal `You put them into a hierarchy.` There is no hierarchy in the design, the mapping framework dynamically clusters and reclusters the pins. We are escaping the scope of the question. The point is that this demonstrates full accessibility would restrict me from using this design, or cost a lot of time to make it accessible.

Comment: I think you are making excuses. How can one put a few thousand pins onto an image and not say NWSE etc.

Comment: @EdHeal `I think you are making excuses. How can one put a few thousand pins onto an image and not say NWSE etc` You are exactly the kind of person I feared would arrive to troll before I submitted this question. You've proved my suspicions. Thank you for this lesson. I'm sorry you could not remain objective.

Comment: I won't be objective, either. You know why? Because I'm totally blind from birth. I excuse people who _don't know_ about accessibility and make inaccessible products. but those who _don't want_ to bother with that because "its' too hard to design", those I can't excuse in no way. And believe me, if I ever know a developer _doesn't want_ to make his/her product accessible, I'll do all my best to spread the idea that this website or product or whatever should not be visited not only by blind people, but all of their sighted environment.

Comment: @AndrePolykanine I want to thank you for this comment, it was very valuable. After reading it, I had a think about what I wanted to do. I made my website with your advice in mind, and it is doing as well as I expected. There is not a single accessibility or screen reader tag anywhere, just the way I like it. Thank you for your words, it really pushed me and I actually benefited from that motivation.